# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level when publishing site via FTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I have recently updated my development machine. In the process of doing so, I installed visual studio 2017 Enterprise as opposed to 2017 Community, this is the only thing that has changed in respect of what I am trying to do.

I 'now' get the following error when publishing an MVC site via FTP;

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

I get what the error means, but I am failing to understand why.

The specific section it is referring to is;

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
    </authentication>
```

The website was previously published using the same source, same profile, to the same server. The site is currently running with the configuration identical to what is being published with no issues. If I publish the site to a local directory and copy the file to the server (in the same place) I get no issues.

I would add that the error is during build, not publish.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have nested web config files ?

Comment: It has the standard web.config in Views, but nothing that defines FormAuthentication and nothing that has changed

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I can get it to work by deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders, but the error comes back during the next build after the next time I publish it.